# Silverstripe - Post data to external URL

Tags: php, forms, post, silverstripe

I have set up a form in Silverstripe that when submitted will take all the data entered, return the form and then add a md5 checksum to the data.
Once that is all done it needs to send to an external URL but I cannot get that working.

```
public function doPayment($data, Form $form) {
    $data['CHECKSUM'] = md5($data['NAME'].$data['SURNAME']);
```

Is there any way to send this?

I tried

```
setFormAction
```

but it doesn't seem to work once the form has already been returned.

Thanks

Comment: May I ask what payment provider you're dealing with here? You might be better off using something like omnipay or even the silverstripe-omnipay module?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Omnipay, it needs to be one of our local providers here.

Comment: I see. You could still implement your own Omnipay gateway… depending of what features you'll need, this might be less work overall.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't reload the form to add the MD5 to it. This way, the user can still modify the form-data before submitting it (thus invalidating the hash).

What you should do instead is take the form data, calculate the hash and send everything directly to the server (eg. the payment provider). You can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) calls or the [guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) library for this.

Using guzzle, your code could look like this:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public function doPayment($data, Form $form) 
{
    $data['CHECKSUM'] = md5($data['NAME'].$data['SURNAME']);

    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://paymentprovider.tld'
    ]);

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://paymentprovider.tld/pay', [
        'form_params' => $data
    ]);

    if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
        // sucesss!
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made this a bit clearer. This is what I am doing currently but I am stuck on sending everything to the payment server.

Comment: @Craig So you're currently using CURL or guzzle, but it doesn't work?

Comment: I did give CURL a try but I couldn't get it to send either. Let me look into CURL a bit more.

Comment: @Craig I added an example using Guzzle… should be much easier than dealing with CURL requests.